# Why Perl in Windows can't rename file with umlaut?

Tags: windows, perl, encoding, rename, diacritics

There is following list of files in directory:

1. 01 Born - Praised - Kissed.flac
2. 02 Wunschkind.flac
3. 03 You've got it.flac
4. 04 Down in this Hole.flac
5. 05 Wälsungenblut.flac
6. ...
   N. 0N Filename

> #Yes, these are the songs of Oomph!

and following program on Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );

my @dirnames;

while ( (my $dirname = <>) =~ /\S/ ) {
    chomp($dirname);
    push (@dirnames, $dirname);
}

foreach my $dirname (@dirnames) {
    opendir (DIR, $dirname);
    while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
        if(length($file)>5) {
            print $file , "\n";
            my $newfile;

            $newfile = substr($file, 0, 2);
            $newfile .= '.';
            $newfile .= substr($file, 2);

            rename ($dirname . '\\' . $file, $dirname . '\\' . $newfile) or die $!;
        }
    }
    closedir DIR;
}
```

that gets the list of directories and renames the files in them by adding dot after number.

Program works correctly on all files, but when it try to rename file with umlaut in the filename, both of the Windows PowerShell and Command Line throw the error that `Permission denied` at the string with `rename` function.

How to solve this problem, guys?

**UPD. Software:**

- Windows 8 x64
- ActiveState ActivePerl 1601 (Perl 5.16)

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($file));` so we can focus our answer a little.

Comment: @ikegami
The result is
$VAR1 = "01. Born - Praised - Kissed.flac";

01. Born - Praised - Kissed.flac
$VAR1 = "02.. Wunschkind.flac";
02.. Wunschkind.flac
$VAR1 = "03.. You've got it.flac";

03.. You've got it.flac

$VAR1 = "04.. Down in this Hole.flac";
04. Down in this Hole.flac
$VAR1 = "05. W?lsungenblut.flac";
05. W?lsungenblut.flac
Permission denied at e:\rename.pl line 20, <> line 2.

Comment: perhaps `Permission denied` prevents rename? :)

Comment: @mpapec All of the files have similar attributes.

Comment: I've only read the question title, maybe didn't understand what you need; but do you have permissions for rename? can you rename from windows cmd line?

Comment: @mpapec Files differ only by names. I have doubts that problem in access rights. The reason why I think so is because I execute it with admin rights.

Comment: "can you rename from windows cmd line"?

Comment: No, cmd line says that command is incorrect. But if I try to rename another file (without umlauts), it works.

Comment: I'll write a proper answer soon, but short answer: The character doesn't exist in your console's code page. Try running `chcp 65001` first. If that doesn't work, you'll need use some Win32:: module.

Comment: I've already tried it, but nothing's changed. I would be grateful when (or if) you write the right code for this goal. I know nothing about using these modules and I believe that your code or answer should help me to learn Perl.

Comment: I can't quite reproduce the problem. Could you provide the four numbers output by `perl -MWin32 -E"say for Win32::GetACP(), Win32::GetOEMCP(), Win32::GetConsoleCP(), Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP();"`, and can you confirm that you see `05 Wälsungenblut.flac` while browsing the dircetory using `explorer` (aka `My Computer`).

Comment: hum... and I can't find a module that can read a directory without using a code page. STill looking...

Comment: Found Win32::FileFind::FileData, but it fails its tests for me. Gotta run again

Comment: After running `chcp 65001` cmd shows `1251`, `866`, `65001` and `65001`. Without running it shows `866` instead of `65001`. And yes, I see umlauts in `explorer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl's `readdir` uses a legacy interface ("ANSI") since it can only handle file names consisting of bytes due to its unix heritage.

The "ANSI" interface uses a single-byte character encoding known as a code page. Your system's code page is [1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1251), and it doesn't provide a means of encoding "ä", so file names containing "ä" cannot be returned by `readdir`.

You need to avoid this "ANSI" interface (`FindFirstFileA`) and gain access to `FindFirstFileW`. This will provide the file name in UTF-16le, which you can pass to [Win32API::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32API%3a%3aFile)'s `MoveFileExW`. [Win32::Unicode::Dir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aUnicode%3a%3aDir)'s `open`+`fetch` does just that.

It's a dismal state of affairs. I've been meaning to address it, but it would be an extensive project.

```
use utf8;
use Win32 qw( );
BEGIN {
   binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(cp'.Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP().')');
   binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(cp'.Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP().')');
}
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use Encode              qw( encode );
use Win32::Unicode::Dir qw( mvtreeW );
use Win32API::File      qw( MoveFileExW );

my $dir_qfn = '.';

my $wdir = Win32::Unicode::Dir->new();
$wdir->open($dir_qfn)
   or die("Can't open $dir_qfn: ".$wdir->error());

for ($wdir->fetch()) {
   next if /^\.\.?\z/;
   next if length() <= 5;

   say;

   my $o_fn = $_;
   s/^..\K/./s;
   my $n_fn = $_;

   MoveFileExW(
      encode('UTF-16le', "$dir_qfn/$o_fn\0"),
      encode('UTF-16le', "$dir_qfn/$n_fn\0"),
      0,  # or MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING
   )
      or die("Can't rename $o_fn to $n_fn: $^E\n");
}

$wdir->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the directory as if it was in UTF-8, but you are really in Windows-1252 encoding. Lose the `use open qw(...)` and it should work.

Comment: I have tried this method hour ago. No result. Could you try it on your own machine?

Comment: "You are reading the directory as if it was in UTF-8," huh? No. `use open` doesn't affect `readdir` in the least.

Comment: I just did -- it worked here! When I leave the `use open`, I get the "No such file or directory at j:um.pl line 24, <> line 2." error message... but if I take it out, it renames all the files on the directory. Are you getting your input from stdin or from a file? In what encoding is the input?

Comment: @Massa, he's getting it from `readdir`, not `STDIN` or a file.

Comment: @ikegami: it seems that when I `use open`, `readdir` is converting the file names from win1252 to utf8 -- if I try to open the files, it gives me the forementioned message, and if I print them, it prints "Conversão" as "ConversÃ£o" (ie, utf-8 decoded bytes). look: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5808257

Comment: @Massa, he's getting a question mark, not the UTF-8 encoding of the name. I just need to do a bit of testing to find the exact answer, but I can't do that right now.

Comment: @kamensky, what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @Massa, Windows 8, does it matter?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your "substitute by question mark" behaviour, but I am not getting it. Which perl distribution for windows are you using (msys, strawberry perl, active perl, etc.)?

Comment: please, try another thing: **with** the `use open` on, do `use encode qw( _utf8_on _utf8_off );` in the top of your script and do `_utf8_on($file)` just before the `print $file,` line....

Comment: @Massa `Undefined subroutine &main::_utf8_on called at e:\rename.pl line 22, <> line 2.`

Comment: No, result is similar to result, described in question.

Comment: NEVER use `_utf8_on`. Use `decode_utf8` instead. And it makes no sense to decode from UTF-8.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have access to "rename.pl"? can you do

```
perl rename.pl "s/^(\d\d)/$1./" *flac
```

?

Comment: Can't open s/^(\d\d)/./: No such file or directory at e:\rename.pl line 11.

Use of uninitialized value $dirname in pattern match (m//) at e:\rename.pl line 11.

Comment: I meant the **other** rename.pl, sorry about that...

http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL

Comment: This rename.pl does:
`mkdir s/^(;
mkdir s/^(\d;
mkdir s/^(\d\d);
c:\rename.pl can't open s/^(\d\d)/./: No such file or directory;`